# Приоритетная очередь. Вставка

Tags: java, очередь

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять принцип вставки в приоритетную очередь, а конкретно сдвига вверх. К примеру я имею массив состоящий из 6 элементов.

```
int[] j = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30};
```

И хочу внести в него элемент `item = 16;`

```
public void insert(long item) // Вставка элемента
{
    int j;
    if(nItems==0) // Если очередь пуста,
        queArray[nItems++] = item; // вставляем в ячейку 0
    else // Если очередь содержит элементы
    {
        for(j=nItems-1; j>=0; j--) // Перебор в обратном направлении
        {
            if( item > queArray[j] ) // Если новый элемент больше,
                queArray[j+1] = queArray[j]; // сдвинуть вверх
            else // Если меньше,
                break; // сдвиг прекращается
        }
        queArray[j+1] = item; // Вставка элемента
        nItems++;
    }
}
```

Я прохожу по массиву, до тех пор пока значение item не превысит j-е значение. Т.е при `j = 2, queArray[j]` будет равен 15. Далее нужно сдвинуть элементы вверх. За это по идее должна отвечать эта часть:

```
queArray[j+1] = queArray[j];
```

Но ведь таким образом, я не увеличиваю размер массива и не двигаю его, я просто присваиваю `queArray[j+1]` значению `queArray[j]`, 20 = 15 и таким образом просто убираю значение 20 из массива и заменяю его на 15. Где я неправ?

Comment: сдвиг начинается с предпоследнего элемента и затрет последний, да

Comment: Почему с предпоследнего, если сдвинуть нужно после 15, т.е. после `j = 2;`? И разве можно в очереди, просто затирать элемент, вместо сдвига. Это пример из алгоритмов и структур данных Лафора. Мб там код неверный, вы не могли бы проверить?

Comment: потому что цикл начинается с `nItems - 1` и идет вниз

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас обычный массив. При инициализации ему присваивается фиксированная длина в 6 элементов. Добавить элементы в массив не получится. Можно только менять уже имеющиеся.

**Для того, чтобы добавлять/менять/удалять нужно использовать не обычный массив а** `ArrayList`.

Так вы сможете просто добавить элемент в `ArrayList` и сортировать с помощью компаратора

Answer (score 2):

Так к слову, у Вас идет обычная инициализация массива(фиксированный размер) и это никак не очередь. Для более детального изучения проблемы почитайте про такие коллекции, реализующие интерфейс Queue.